# CS50 Recover runs and recovers all files except the first one

Tags: cs50

My question is regarding the Recover assignment as part of CS50.

The code is running (finally) and it produces 50 JPEG files, and most of them are the correct images, except the first file is not an image, therefore it  doesn't pass check50.

I have spent a long time trying to figure out what the problem is but I cannot pinpoint it so I am hoping someone might be able to help me out so I can move on.

Thanks in advance! Here is my code:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: Name of Memory Card File\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char *readfile = argv[1];

    // open memory card file
    FILE *card_ptr = fopen(readfile, "r");
    if (card_ptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", readfile);
        return 2;
    }

    //Declare a buffer to read into
    unsigned char *buffer = malloc(512);

    //to check if we have already found a file
    bool (jpgAlreadyNew) = false;

    //declare counter for the number of files found and a file pointer
    int filenumber = 0;
    FILE *new_jpg_ptr = NULL;
    char filename[8];

    //read in bytes until reach EOF
    while (fread(buffer, 1, 512, card_ptr) != 0x00)
    {
        //if we reach the header pattern of bytes
        if (buffer [0] == 0xff && buffer [1] == 0xd8 && buffer [2] == 0xff && (buffer [3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {

            //if there is not already a JPEG file found
            if (!jpgAlreadyNew)
            {
                //change the bool value
                (jpgAlreadyNew) = true;

                //open new file
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", filenumber);
                new_jpg_ptr = fopen(filename, "w");
                if (new_jpg_ptr == NULL)
                    {
                        return 3;
                    }
                //add to counter of files found
                filenumber++;

                //write files from buffer into new img file
                fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, new_jpg_ptr);

            }

            //if there is already a JPEG file found
            if (jpgAlreadyNew)

            {
                //close the previous file which would now be complete
                fclose(new_jpg_ptr);

                //open new file
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", filenumber);
                new_jpg_ptr = fopen(filename, "w");
                if (new_jpg_ptr == NULL)
                    {
                        return 4;
                    }
                //add to counter of files found
                filenumber++;

                //write files from buffer into new img file
                fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, new_jpg_ptr);

            }

        }

        // else if we do not see pattern of header bytes
        else
        {
            //if already found a jpg file which is open then write the bytes to that file
            if (jpgAlreadyNew)
              {
                  fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, new_jpg_ptr);
              }
            //if no file found yet, discard and move on
            if (!jpgAlreadyNew)
              {
                  continue;
              }
        }
    }

    //free memory
    free (buffer);

    //close pointers and end program successfully
    fclose(card_ptr);
    fclose(new_jpg_ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's walk through the program starting with finding the first jpeg signature:

This `if (!jpgAlreadyNew)` evaluates to true, so it enters the if block; the first thing it does is `(jpgAlreadyNew) = true;`. When it is done creating the file and writing the first block, what happens next? This `if (jpgAlreadyNew)`. Which *also* evaluates to true. So it closes 000.jpg and moves along.

Since `jpgAlreadyNew` is a boolean, an `if {} else {}` construct would suffice.

Comment: Thank you so much, having the ``if {} else {}`` only makes total sense!  I have figured it out now.